# Copy and paste between inputs with a button - Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to copy the data entered in one input and paste them into another by using a button to do it.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

You have ideas how it can be done with JavaScript / Angular 1? Or another QA that answers this question?

Comment: Assign value of ng-model scope property from other ng-model scope property in an event handler. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @SankarRaj I have not tested anything yet, I have no idea

Comment: Suggest you study some form tutorials since this is really quite trivial in angular and Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 0):

Using angularJS

**controller**

```
// your first input data
$scope.country1 = "";

// your second input data
$scope.country2 = "";

// the copy function
$scope.copy = function() {
 $scope.country2 = $scope.country1;
}
```

**view**

```
<!-- Your first input -->
<input type="text" ng-model="country1" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"/>

<!-- Your button -->
<button ng-click="copy()">Copy</button>

<!-- Your second input -->
<input type="text" ng-model="country2" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }"/>
```

Comment: use debounce wherever the digest cycle is auto kicked off. will be useful when the application scales.

Comment: You're right, i edited with a debounce use-case example